# Using MapKit in SceneKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, scenekit

This must be a very basic question to the pros out there. I have done quiet a bit of googling and cant find the answer I wanted.

Is it possible to use MapKit in SceneKit to render animated characters on the map ? If it is not possible how is it done when it comes to Open World type games. I basically want to make a game that has the world map as background which can be zoomed in/out. Also need to show some game options based on user's location.

All the examples I have seen is using a contained background in which the characters/objects are rendered.

Edit:

I have the following in my `didMove()` method

```
class GameScene: SKScene, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        var map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()
        map.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height - 50)
        self.view?.addSubview(map)
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of tricks you can do,  do you plan on having it only top down?

Comment: Yes it will only be top down. Is there some resources that you can point me to ? I am not sure how to look for to be honest ;)

Comment: Then I would render your SCNScene with a transparent background on top of your MapKit view

Comment: Check my edit.. Do I add the SCNScene to the main view like I added the map ?

Comment: I do not deal with SceneKit often  the heirarchy should look like this: MainView -> MapView -> SCNView

Comment: right so in my case the `MainView` is `SKScene` are u saying i should ditch that and use a normal view and then MapView and then SCNView on top ?

Comment: your MainView right now is SCNView, not SKScene (I think you mean SCNScene? Scenes are not views)   If you have nothing else going on, you can make your MapKit the main view,  but in my preference, I like having a regular UIView as the top most layer, just in case

Comment: Check my edit again. I have included the class declaration too. Looks like its inheriting `SKScene` so right the view on it is `SKView`

Comment: So you are doing Sprite Kit? not Scene Kit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116812/discussion-between-deepak-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: I would not be doing what you are doing in code, do this in the storyboard,  separate presentation and logic as much as possible

Comment: @Deepak I don't understand very well what do you want to achieve, I think you want to use some snapshots from mapKit (mkmapsnapshotter) to render your nodes with SCNRenderer..

Answer (score 0):

You can render a sceneview in a annotationview, and render it in the mapview function "viewFor".

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.